# Determining the value this sequence converges towards

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem at hand:
$$
a_n =  \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right)}
$$

My best guess is that this will converge but I am struggling to show what it converges towards. My first step was to do:
$$
\ln(a_n) = \ln\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right)}\right)
$$

So that we are left with:
$$
\ln(a_n) = \left( \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right) 
\left(\ln\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)\right)
$$

But cannot figure out what to do past this point. Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated, not looking to have the answer handed to me but at this point I am stuck.

Thank you :)

Comment: $\ln(1/n)=-\ln(n).$ This will give you a surprise about your sequence.

Comment: Calculate some values, for a few hundred values of $n$. It’s a dozen lines of code in any decent programming language, or you can use a spreadsheet. This won’t prove anything, but will give you some guidance.